# How can I programmatically change the parse mode?

Tags: 7, views, search

We have a view that works with Search API and Solr search. The multiple search terms work with single quotes and with no quotes. I want to make the search terms work with double quotes as well. The issue is also listed here without a fix:

https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/2141575

I found that I can change the parse mode in the View > Query > Settings to direct method and the term with double quotes work just fine. I want to make this change using hooks. I have tried `hook_search_api_views_query_alter` and it does not work. Does anyone know how to change the parse mode in the query settings using hooks?

Answer (score 2):

On Drupal 7, I've achieved this by using `hook_views_pre_build()` since this hook is executed before `hook_views_pre_execute()` and `hook_search_api_views_query_alter()`. Using code similar to the following will do the job.

```php
$options = $view->display_handler->get_option('query');
$options['options']['parse_mode'] = 'TYPE_OF_PARSE_MODE';
$view->display_handler->set_option('query', $options);
```

Note that `TYPE_OF_PARSE_MODE` can be:

- Direct query - direct
- Single term - single
- Multiple terms - terms